# How right use preloaded database in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to use preloaded database. The database must be annexed to the application, and then be able to update. I have a number of doubts about how to connect it to avoid problems. I ask that answered professionals who deal with the problem. Thank you.

1. If my base is greater than 1 MB, it pops up an error D / asset (909): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX. Can be broken down into pieces smaller than 1 megabyte, and can be changed to increase (". Jpg", ". Jpeg", ". Png", ". Gif", ". wav", ". mp2", ". mp3", ". ogg", ". aac", ". mpg", ". mpeg", ". mid", ". midi", ". smf", ". jet", ". rtttl", ". imy", ". xmf", ". mp4", ". m4a", ". m4v", ".3 gp", ".3 gpp", ".3 g2", ".3 gpp2", ". amr", ". awb", ". wma", ". wmv"). Which option is better (easier - change the extension).
2. Might fail "No such table android_metadata" but I added manually to the database en_US, but what if the application multilanguage?
3. When reading the database, I use the method mDb = getReadableDatabase ();, but I'm at the end of a close reading - mDb.close (); As they say on the Internet may not care any error Unable to open database file. This is especially for the devices HTC.

The following quote code

```
public class QuestionsDbAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mantestQuestions";

public static final String TABLE_QUESTIONS = "Questions";
public static final String QUESTIONS_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String QUESTIONS_COLUMN_QUESTION ="Question";

public static final String TABLE_ANSWERS = "Answers";
public static final String ANSWERS_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String ANSWERS_COLUMN_QUESTION_ID = "QuestionId";
public static final String ANSWERS_COLUMN_ANSWER = "Answer";
public static final String ANSWERS_COLUMN_POINT = "Point";

private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private final Context mContext;

private boolean mCreateDatabase = false;
private boolean mUpgradeDatabase = false;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access
 * the application's assets and resources
 * @param context
 */
public QuestionsDbAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.questionDbVersion));

    mContext = context;
}

public void initializeDatabase(String path) {
    DATABASE_PATH = path;
    getWritableDatabase();

    if(mUpgradeDatabase) {
        mContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    if(mCreateDatabase || mUpgradeDatabase) {
        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    close();

    InputStream input = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();

    getWritableDatabase().close();
}

public QuestionsDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDb = getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void CleanUp() {
    mDb.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    mCreateDatabase = true;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    mUpgradeDatabase = true;
}

/**
 * Public helper methods
 */

public Cursor getQuestionById(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, TABLE_QUESTIONS,
            new String[] { QUESTIONS_COLUMN_ID, QUESTIONS_COLUMN_QUESTION }, QUESTIONS_COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getAnswerById(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, TABLE_ANSWERS,
            new String[] { ANSWERS_COLUMN_ID, ANSWERS_COLUMN_QUESTION_ID, ANSWERS_COLUMN_ANSWER, ANSWERS_COLUMN_POINT },
            ANSWERS_COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getAnswersByQuestionId(long questionId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, TABLE_ANSWERS, new String[] {ANSWERS_COLUMN_ANSWER, ANSWERS_COLUMN_POINT},
            ANSWERS_COLUMN_QUESTION_ID + "=" + questionId, null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}

public long getCount() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_QUESTIONS;
    SQLiteStatement statement = mDb.compileStatement(sql);
    long count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to update, you'll have to make a writable copy anyway, so you might as well compress the original and only attempt to access (as a database) the uncompressed writable copy that you make.  The other options would be to download the DB separately after install, or try to work out some scheme were a writable DB tracks changes against a read-only original.

Comment: Yes, I did copy the method `copyDataBase ()`, and then in the working database will be updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need this messy code here is nice solution for you [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: Wow, great article, thanks! I try to implement it right now, I will write the final results! **THANK YOU VERY MUCH!**

Comment: want to thank me ??? you can check my answer ! perhaps this way how people than each other in stackoverflow :) have a nice day.

Comment: Nammari, help me understand please. When I try to use the method, `update()` in MyDatabase.java. I get the error **The method update (SQLiteDatabase, ContentValues, String, null) is undefined for the type SQLiteQueryBuilder** `public void setSets(ContentValues cv, int idColIndex) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
  SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
  String sqlTables = "Sets";
  qb.setTables(sqlTables);
  String selection = "_id = " + idColIndex;
  qb.update(db, cv, selection, null);
  db.close();`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you just need to store your images in the mobile app but if its size is very big then retrieve it from server, thanks for @confucius for this article it really helps, and here's another step by step tutorial which explains [how to use sqlite browser to make a pre-loaded database in android](http://androidgifts.com/import-sqlite-database-into-android-using-sqlite-browser/)